# JavaScript object, call on page

Tags: javascript

I have one javascript file that houses all the functions for my website, stored it a large object, like this:

```
var Example = {

init : function(){
    alert('init');
},

page_one : function(){
    alert('this is page 1');
},

page_two : function(){
    alert('this is page 2');
}
```

}

Now I like to open a simple script tag on the different pages, and on page1 do `Example.page_one();` and on page2 do `Example.page_two();`

But this doesn't work. When I call those in the same file as where die Example object is made, then it works, but not if I include that file in a page, and call it from there.

The Example object does show up in the `window` object

Can someone help me?

Comment: do you get an error in the javascript console?

Comment: are you calling example after including the file or before including file?

Comment: Are you "including" the Javascript file on each page?  See the following: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp

Comment: Make sure you place the script tags after this script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I fixed it myself. Stupid fault.

My code was like this:

```
  <script defer src="js/scripts.js"></script>
  <script>
    AdminDashboard.notificationMessages();
    AdminDashboard.setupMenu();
    AdminDashboard.setupFileInput('#new_slideshow_image');
    AdminDashboard.setupSlideCrop();
  </script>
```

And the problem seemed to be with defer. The object did load, but after the script fired that called to it.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you will create example object in your page where you have included it, it will override example object.  Try to use direct functions rather than this approach.

Comment: Please, considering the rest of your answer is in proper English, don't use leetspeak such as "u hv"